# Complete metric spaces and completion from Munkres

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

I was reading the chapter about complete metric spaces and I've noticed some moments which I would like to clarify:

**Question 1:** We have shown that $\rho (\Phi(a),\Phi(b))=d(a,b)$ i.e. $\Phi$ preserves the distances.

Also we have to show that $\Phi$ is an imbedding, right? It means that $\Phi:(X,d)\hookrightarrow (\mathcal{B}(X,\mathbb{R}),\rho)$ is bijective mapping such that $\Phi, \Phi^{-1}$ are continuous. Injectivity follows easily from the isometry. And continuity of $\Phi$ from $\rho (\Phi(a),\Phi(b))=d(a,b)$ and continuity of $\Phi^{-1}$ from $\rho (z_1,z_2)=d(\Phi^{-1}(z_1),\Phi^{-1}(z_2))$, where $z_1,z_2$ are points from the image set of $\Phi$. Is my reasoning correct?

**Question 2:** He claims that the subspace $\overline{h(X)}$ of $Y$ is complete. It follows since $Y$ is complete and $\overline{h(X)}$ is closed subset, right?

Would be very grateful for help!

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, an isometry is automatically 1-1 and continuous (Take $\delta=\epsilon$ uniformly) and its inverse (from $h[X]$ back to $X$) is also an isometry (thus likewise continuous).

And the closed set in a complete space is complete is the simplest argument.

Comment: Thanks dear Henno!